# Regex filter for numbers and percentage

Tags: regex

Regex filter for numbers and percentage

Hello,

Once again I ask for help from the community to help me with regex strings for numbers and percentages, I have the following scenario:

↑: 4.265%

↑: 23.392%

↑: 52.126%

↑: 172.373%

↑: 2452.182%

I need to create 2 regex strings, the first one that filters any percentage above 20.000%, the second one needs to filter from 50.000% onwards, I would like the percentage filter to go to infinity, if it is not possible we can work with a range of up to 10000.000%

An important note, unfortunately there is no possibility to use programming codes, I am using a third party platform to perform this filtering and it only supports regex, so there is no other way but to use regex

Thanks again!

I don't have deep knowledge in regex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ECMAScript ([try it](https://regex101.com/r/F7yVdA/2)):

```
(?<!\d\.?)       #       a full number,
(?:              # Match                consists of
  [2-9]\d        # a digit from 2 to 9 followed by another digit
|                # or
  [1-9]\d{2,}    # a digit from 1 to 9 followed by 2 or more digits
)                # 
(?:\.\d+)?       # followed by a dot and 1 or more digits, optionally.
(?<!             # Assure that what we caught
  (?<!\d\.?)     # is not a full number
  20             # that starts with literal '20'
  (?:\.0+)?      # followed by a dot and 1 or more zeroes, optionally.
)                # 
%                # Ends with literal '%'
```

PCRE2 ([try it](https://regex101.com/r/C5fhtl/3)):

```
(?<!\d\.)        # Same as (?<!\d\.), but
(?<!\d)          # splitted to two negative lookaheads
(?:              # 
  20             # Match literal '20', followed by
  \.0*[1-9]\d*   # a dot, 0 or more zeroes, a digit from 1 to 9 and 0 or more digits
|                # or
  (?:            # 
    2[1-9]       # 21 to 29
  |              # or
    [3-9]\d      # 30 to 99
  |              # or
    [1-9]\d{2,}  # 100 to infinity
  )              #
  (?:\.\d+)?     # followed by a dot and 1 or more digits, optionally
)                # 
%                # Ends with literal '%'
```

Comment: Sorry, there are some special characters before the numbers I'm trying to filter, I thought just entering the numbers in the string would work, however it didn't, I'm editing the post and inserting the special characters, any ideas on how to create a string for this new updated information in the post?
Thanks a lot for the help.

Comment: @Doom Updated. Does it work for you?

Comment: The first option worked perfectly (ECMAScript), thanks a lot for the help, thanks to everyone else who helped too

Answer (score 0):

First, to match a percent value, I have this simple regex

```
^\d+(.\d+)?%$
```

This regex will match any numbers (int or float) followed by a `%`
Explaination:

- `^` start of line anchor
- `\d+` match one or as many as possible digits
- `(.\d+)?` match a decimal point and a fractional part `(.\d+)` and is optional (`?`), that could match `12,345%` or just `12%`
- `%` match a percent symbol
- `$` end of line anchor

Example: [Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/O0LS0f/1)

From that, I will move further to match percent higher than `20%`:

```
^[2-9]\d(.\d+)?%$|^[1-9]\d{2,}(.\d+)?%$
```

In this regex, I have two parts, seperated by a OR token `|`:

1. The first one `^[2-9]\d(.\d+)?%$` to match percent that have 2 digits, so to match percent higher than `20%`, it much start with digit from [2-9] and followed by any digit.

   - `^` start of line anchor
   - `[2-9]` match one digit in range 2-9
   - `\d` match a single digit
   - `(.\d+)?` match a decimal point and a fractional part `(.\d+)` and is optional (`?`)`
   - `%` match a percent symbol
   - `$` end of line anchor
2. The second part `^[1-9]\d{2,}(.\d+)?%` will match percent value that have at least 3 digits so it must start with [1-9] and followed by 2 or more digits:

   - `^` start of line anchor
   - `[1-9]` match one digit in range 1-9
   - `\d{2,}` match two or more digits
   - `(.\d+)?` match a decimal point and a fractional part `(.\d+)` and is optional (`?`)`
   - `%` match a percent symbol
   - `$` end of line anchor

Example: [Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/DuQ4VG/1)

So to match value higher than 50%, simply change from `2` to `5`

```
^[5-9]\d(.\d+)?%$|^[1-9]\d{2,}(.\d+)?%$
```

**Note:** From this point I realized that I misunderstand OP's condition, I though it would be match value higher or equal, so my regex wont work in case of match only higher value, @InSync has provided a flawlessly regex for that case. But I will post my effort and hope it will help you learn a bit more about regex!

Comment: Sorry, there are some special characters before the numbers I'm trying to filter, I thought just entering the numbers in the string would work, however it didn't, I'm editing the post and inserting the special characters, any ideas on how to create a string for this new updated information in the post?
Thanks a lot for the help.

Comment: @Doom you could remove the start of line anchor `^`, btw will the number always match the format `123.456` (always include a decimal point and fractional part? If yes, you should remove the optional from fractional match group. The regex should be something like this `[2-9]\d\.\d+%$|[1-9]\d{2,}\.\d+?%$`. [Regex101 example](https://regex101.com/r/g7KzTB/1)

Comment: Thank you very much!
Your help helped solve my problem!